# Custom Page Control for PageViewController

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uipagecontrol

Is there a way to customize the page control of the `PageViewController`?
Or should I use a segmented control as page control?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But than you need to control it by your self. Just add you view as subview of `UIPageViewController` view.

Comment: I mean to custimize that gray balls... I want to transform them into text labels, for example, and when the selected view is hitten, the text turn into other color... like segmented controller.